# How can I compare the trimmed and untrimmed lengths of fields without retyping the field name?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

Basically, I want to check if there are any spaces to the right of the text in a varchar field. To do so, I want to compare `DATALENGTH(fieldName)` to `DATALENGTH(RTRIM(fieldName))`.

This isn’t so hard.

Only thing is, that I need to do it for all the varchar fields in five tables. It comes out to about 250 fields that I need to compare this way. Is there a way I can put all those field names into one query without typing each one’s name 2x?

I'm using this query to get the names of the fields I need to look at.

```
SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = 
    (SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE name='tableName') 
AND system_type_id = 167
```

(Using SQL Server 2005)

Thanks!

Comment: You'd only have to type the names in once if you used `where column like '% '` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just let SQL Server generate the code for me if it's just typing that is the problem:

```
SELECT
    'SELECT * FROM ' + o.name + ' WHERE DATALENGTH(' + c.name + ') > DATALENGTH(RTRIM(' + c.name + '))'
FROM
    sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON
    c.object_id = o.object_id AND
    c.system_type_id = 167
WHERE
    o.name = 'tableName'
```

Are you sure that type 167 is all that you need to check though?

Comment: Yes - I only need the fields that are varchars

Comment: I was just thinking that NVARCHAR might also be important, but maybe you don't use these or maybe they aren't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive how to accomplish this in SQL, though I suspect you will need to generate a SQL string and then execute. I use Notepad++ for this sort of thing all the time.

1. Copy list of fieldnames into new files separate by line breaks
2. Ctrl+R
3. Enable Regular Expressions
4. Find ^(.+)$
5. Replace with "\1LenMatch AS CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(\1) = DATALENGTH(RTRIM(\1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END," or whatever sql line you need and include \1 where you would like the field name to go.

Answer (score 0):

Taking you literally, if you want to avoid typing field names twice, get SQL Server to do the typing for you.

```
Select ' Or DataLength(' + Name + ')<>DataLength(RTrim(' + Name + '))'
  From sys.Columns
 Where Object_ID=Object_ID('Employees')
   And System_Type_ID=167
```

(Note that you don't really need the explicit reference to sys.tables, the Object_ID function will do that for you!)

However, what I think you're really asking for, is how to detect if a value ends with one or more spaces without comparing lengths in this way. The answer is to use a stored function.

```
Create Function Dbo.EndsWithSpaces(@Value Varchar(8000)) Returns Bit
As Begin
  Return Case When DataLength(@Value)=DataLength(RTrim(@Value)) Then 0
              Else 1 End
End
```

Now you can check for trailing spaces for any value: `Dbo.EndsWithSpaces(Value)=1` Of course, you can still have SQL Server generate the end of your Where clause for you:

```
Select ' Or Dbo.EndsWithSpaces(' + Name + ')=1'
  From sys.Columns
 Where Object_ID=Object_ID('Employees')
   And System_Type_ID=167
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to reverse the string and check for the first space.  If it's a 1, there is a space at the end of your data.  If it's 0, there are no spaces.  If it's greater than 1, there's a space but it's not at the end of the data.

Ex:

```
Select Columns...
From   Table
Where  CharIndex(' ', Reverse(ColumnName)) = 1
```